# Docker containers work on port 80 only

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx, docker

I tried this on multiple machines (Win10 and server 2016), same result
using this tutorial: 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#set-up-tab-completion-in-powershell

This works

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

Any other port, fails with

```
docker run -d -p 8099:8099 --name webserver nginx --> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Looks like  Docker/nginx is listening failing on this port, but failing.  Telneting to this port shows that the request goes through, but disconnects right away.  This is different from when a port is not being listened to on at all.

Comment: Try `docker run -d -p 8099:80 --name webserver nginx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ports in that list. The first port is the one docker publishes on the host for you to connect to remotely. The second port is where to send that traffic in the container. Docker doesn't modify the application, so the application itself needs to be listening on that second port. By default, nginx listens on port 80. Therefore, you could run:

```
docker run -d -p 8099:80 --name webserver nginx
```

To publish on port 8099 and send that traffic to an app inside the container listening on port 80.

Comment: Great, so where to mod the port on nginx?

Comment: Why do you need to change the port inside the container? This would be the nginx config file for nginx specifically, but it varies by app.

Comment: Can I have multiple apps running on port 80 internally?

Comment: Yes, each container runs in it's own network namespace by default.